# What is the meaning of this picture?

Tags: steven-universe

In the song sequence at the beginning of *Steven Universe Future* we see this picture:

[image]

What is it? It definitely isn't composed of scenes from the four episodes in the set. Is it a sort of montage of villains from the past episodes? The presence of Jasper and Aquamarine might suggest that, as does the tall figure who looks rather like White Diamond. That said, I don't remember her being so magenta or angry, and I am at a loss with regard to multi-headed cactus Steven and twin Lapis Lazulis.

Comment: There will be _other_ episodes in the series, beyond the 4 ones aired December 7th, so I guess we will find out later.

Comment: Cactus monster: Steven probably licked a cactus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the order of the episode they appear in, these characters are:

- **Jasper** (episode 1 *"Little Homeschool"*): after being un-corrupted at the end of *"Change Your Mind"*, she has been living alone in the forest near Beach City, refusing to join the other gems and attend the Cristal Gems' lessons about how to live peacefully on Earth;
- **Bluebird Azurite** (episode 5 *"Bluebird"*): she is the fusion of Aquamarine and Eyeball Ruby, and is welcomed at Little Homeworld despite Steven's doubts;
- **two Lapislazulis** (episode 8 *"Why So Blue"*): even after the end of the Gem Empire they keep terraforming an alien planet, menacing the local organic lifeforms;
- **Cactus Steven** (episode 10 *"Prickly Pair"*): a cactus Steven inadvertently gives life to
- **White Diamond** (episode 17 *"Homeworld Bound"*): she is pink-tinted because she is channeling an angry Steven
- the big, spiky, godzilla monster in the background is a self-deprecating **Steven** (episode 19 *"I Am My Monster"*), convinced that he has become a dangerous monster